# Android Espresso: ViewPager does not have adapter instance

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-testing, android-espresso

I´m using in my Android (4.0+) app fragment (in Activity) with Tab bar.

I want to create Espresso test but if I create main Activity and open the fragment. I get this Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewPager does not have adapter instance.
at com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip.setViewPager(PagerSlidingTabStrip.java:177)
at cz.villamemories.detoxme.staticcontent.StaticContentFragment.onCreateView(StaticContentFragment.java:197)
```

My code in fragment:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mViewPagerAdapter = new StaticContentPagerAdapter(
                this.getChildFragmentManager(), mItemsList, categories);

        mPager.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);

        mTabs.setViewPager(mPager); //line 197
```

Do you have some tip where can be a problem? What is wrong?

Comment: No...do you have some tip?

Comment: Unfortunately not... I have the same issue :(

Comment: maybe please add like (plus) to this question and someone will answer...

Comment: I've ended up switching from the PagerSlidingTabStrip to the new TabLayout from the design library and the problem is fixed.

Comment: In the second code box you point out "line 197". Unfortunately the stack trace says it should be inside onCreateView() instead of onActivityCreated(), which means you are looking at the wrong place. You should post new, correct logs/code snippets

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the issue with ViewPager in fragment. This problem occurs me because of my viewpager has a multiple root elements.

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class FragmentTest {

private static final String TAG = "FragmentTest";

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivity = new ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity.class);

@Test
public void checkTabSwiping() {
    onView(nthChildOf(withId(R.id.main_content), 5)).check(matches(withId(R.id.homecontentgrouppager)));
}

public static Matcher<View> firstChildOf(final Matcher<View> parentMatcher) {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("with first child view of type parentMatcher");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {

            if (!(view.getParent() instanceof ViewGroup)) {
                return parentMatcher.matches(view.getParent());
            }
            ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            return parentMatcher.matches(view.getParent()) && group.getChildAt(0).equals(view);

        }
    };
}
public static Matcher<View> nthChildOf(final Matcher<View> parentMatcher,
                                       final int childPosition){
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("with " + childPosition + " child view of type parentMatcher");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
            if (!(view.getParent() instanceof ViewGroup)) {
                return parentMatcher.matches(view.getParent());
            }

            ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            return parentMatcher.matches(view.getParent()) && view.equals(group.getChildAt(childPosition));
        }
    };
}
}
```

and this is my homefragment.xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:background="@color/black"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/promotionalviewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/size_5"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerCountDots"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope it may help you to create a test case in Expresso Framework.